# How to grant permissions to database but restrict to certain schemas?

Tags: permissions, schema, azure-sql-database, role

I am new to database administration and work within a small team of data analysts trying to modernise. We have recently set up an Azure SQL DB server we are accessing using SQL Server Management Studio.

We have an admin account and I have created a user login for each of us for day-to-day work. I would like all user logins to have the ability to create, drop, select etc. freely for all objects where the schema is unspecified or specified as "dbo" but to only have read-only permissions where the schema is specified as  "testschema". I have attempted this using the following code from the admin account:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'testschema')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [testschema] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END

---- Create permissions group:
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'team_member', 'Mel';

-- GRANT BLANKET PERMISSIONS
GRANT CONTROL, ALTER, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO team_member;

-- REVOKE PERMISSIONS TO SPECIFIED SCHEMAS
DENY CONTROL, ALTER, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES,
          UPDATE ON SCHEMA::testschema TO team_member;

-- ALLOW TO SELECT AND VIEW ON THESE SCHEMAS
GRANT SELECT, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::testschema TO team_member;
```

I have been playing around with granting, revoking and denying permissions to myself all morning but I can't seem to get the permissions settings correct so that my user account can create and drop tables with the "dbo" schema and see and select from tables with the "testschema" schema, but can't drop/alter/delete tables with the "testschema" schema.

Can anyone advise on the correct syntax for doing this?

EDIT: I have altered my original code slightly to DENY rather than REVOKE and instead of general permissions I have set dbo-specific schema permissions. The permissions are given as follows and appear to be correct, but team_member users still can not see or select from any testschema tables (there are no other currently-used schemas beyond "testschema" and "dbo").

[image: permissions table view]

Comment: `DENY` instead of `REVOKE`

Comment: Thanks! I have tried DENY instead of REVOKE, but now user "Mel" can't even see tables using the "testschema" schema in the object explorer, and attempting a SELECT statement results in:

"The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'keep_this', database 'DATABASE', schema 'testschema'."

Is there any way I can give read-only access to this schema?

Comment: Try your first grant `ON SCHEMA::dbo` and then the second one without any revoke/deny commands

Comment: You mentioned you are new so this could be useful [Introduction to SQL Server Security](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/data-protection-and-privacy/introduction-to-sql-server-security-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but the user is still able to drop "testschema" tables in that case.

Comment: Hi, @Mel, remove deny control permission on testschema, I think it'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `DENY` and a `GRANT` works for me.

For example:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [user_name]
DENY SELECT ON schema::[other_schema] TO [user_name]
DENY SELECT ON schema::[schema_1] TO [user_name]
GRANT SELECT ON schema::[schema_Safe] TO [user_name]
```

If you need to prevent to drop the table by some user, try this:

```
DENY DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.table_to_deny TO restricted_user;
```

Comment: These worked, thanks! I think the problem was including "CONTROL" in any of the overall or schema-specific permissions. As soon as I took it out and denied or granted more specific permissions only they worked fine.

Comment: I am glad to hear that this works for you... Give an upvote if this answer useful to you.

Comment: I get the error **Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself** using `GRANT SELECT ON schema::[other_schema] TO [user_name]`